# What are the prerequisites for a USB device so an OS can be booted from it?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive

I've been reading a bit about it, and although things are more clear to me now, I'm still in the dark about some details.

What determines (apart from having a newer BIOS, the one that enables you to boot from USB) whether an OS can be booted from a USB storage device (be it an external hard drive, solid or mechanical/rotating, an USB flash memory or something else)?

I've booted OSs from USB flash drives, but every once in a while I see a statement that says "you can't boot from this device". So, what is the difference and what should one look out for in that respect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I identify which of my USB drives can be made bootable](http://superuser.com/questions/18809/how-can-i-identify-which-of-my-usb-drives-can-be-made-bootable), [Checking that a USB key can be made bootable?](http://superuser.com/questions/359755/checking-that-a-usb-key-can-be-made-bootable?lq=1)

Comment: **Are you asking what makes a disk image bootable?**  Because it has very little to do with BIOS or UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can temporarily boot from usb for linux, ubuntu etc...... But its not the same with windows, you need to make a bootable usb and write it into one of the drives(partition)....
2. the best software for this according to me is rufus. But u know wat dey say about softwares. Every day ders a better software... So heres the link for it [rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/)